# Task in Task Scheduler with Idle condition starts but never runs

Tags: c#, windows, .net-3.5, scheduled-tasks

My code creates successfully a task in Win 7 Task Scheduler, all conditions and triggers set. The snippet below is setting the idle trigger, I can see it all set in Task Scheduler, so I know it is creating it right. If I click in run on Task Scheduler, the program starts just as expected, so I know the action is right too.

```
Task.Settings.RunOnlyIfIdle = true;
Task.Settings.IdleSettings.StopOnIdleEnd = false;

// The amount of time that the computer must be in an idle state before the task is run.
Task.Settings.IdleSettings.IdleDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
// Value that indicates the amount of time that the Task Scheduler will wait for an idle condition to occur
Task.Settings.IdleSettings.WaitTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);

// Set up the Idle trigger.
trigger = Task.Triggers.Create(_TASK_TRIGGER_TYPE2.TASK_TRIGGER_IDLE);
```

If I wait for the scheduled time and some more, the task starts but it stays with status  **Queued**, even if I left the pc unused for quite a while, the program never runs.

**Why my task runs but the idle condition seems to be never satisfied?**

> I've found this page about how Windows handles the Idle state.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383561(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need the `RunOnlyIfIdle` Setting in your task definition in addition to the idle task trigger.